# Pass arguments for process C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to run ant.bat file in my C# application, but I am struggling of how to pass arguments there.

I have `xmlFile`, `mode` and `date` which I want to pas as strings for the .bat file to work.
What I've tried:

```
void OpenWithArguments(string f)
    {
        Process.Start("ant.bat", file.xml);
    }


 Process process = new Process();
                    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\aa\ant.bat";
                    process.StartInfo.Arguments = file.xml;
                    process.Start();
```

but how to pass several arguments for the `.bat` file?

And by arguments I meant variables that I get from other methods, like:
`string path = file.xml` `string date="2015-05-23" and so on. Can I also pass them the same way?

Comment: It's not the same though

Comment: It is the same, as said there [ProcessInfo.Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx) is just a string, if you want to pass multiple values, you need to add a whitespace between the values.